Intuitive relation between "range" and "group" in a hierachy
I understand that both the terms: range and group are abstract and GP, depending on the circumstances. I'm also aware that a convention may be set in either way. It's also clear to me that perhaps the relation between those may be too vague to state any relation (and perhaps a choice of other term may be beneficial). In this particular case, those are the activities that are going to be monitored, followed up and billed for (irrelevant, since I'm looking for an agnostic hierarchical ordering not related to the actual purpose of the industry).
The issue.
I have a number of items. Those are bundled together into areas of interest, a scope, one might say, so that a property can be assigned to a number of such items at once by referring to its area, instead of individual assignments.
Now, a new requirement has emerged. As the number of areas grows, we'd need an aggregating concept compounding the areas into a super-area. I'd like to retire the term area, partly to eliminate confusion, partly to get rid of this swenglish pseudo-translation.
The best pair of horses in the race, as far my understanding stretches, is: range and group. However, I haven't found any references to an intuitive relation between them. Would a group consist of a number of ranges or rather that a range would contain a number of groups? (The distinction, possibly vaguely, there's a gun to the head, would be unrelated to the current taxonomy, only relying on an intuitive sense of NSE.)
I'm also open to substituting for other terms (which I didn't feel were the best picks, possibly due to my ignorance).

group
range
collection
aggregation
span
set
scope
purview
gamut

I'm also (reluctantly) open to the (disappointing) eventuality that there's no way, no how, never, nada, ziltch to establish a relation between those in a hierarchy (in which case an arbitrary pick is the best one, as good as any other).

This question is very confusing.  Partly this is due to the mixture of metaphors you use  "horses in a race" "gun to the head". I don't see the words "range" and "group" as being in a hierarchy,

@JamesK A "horse pair" is a reference to the default setup when riding a wagon where each horse (of two) support each other. Since I need two terms, it was a way to express that notion (in a slightly poetic metaphor). A "gun to the head" is an idiomatic expression implying that "not sure" must not be used.

You seem to like metaphors, as @JamesK has noted. So maybe borrow from Linnean taxonomy, within which two specific categories seem immediately suitable: lower-level family within class. But if your hierarchy ever needs to be extended, there are other terms within the Linnean system.

@FumbleFingers I really do. In fact, I see that as a sign of eloquence, also allowing for easier understanding (YMMV, of course). As for the Linné and his system, we actually considered it first (him being a Swede and on every 100 krona bill) but the actual words collided too much with other terms in out particular circumstances, regrettably. The extensibility would be nice to have for future cases, an excellent point.

Well, I suppose it's up to you, but your explanation of "horse pair" doesn't reflect anything I'm familiar with, and I'm still totally baffled as to what your "gun to the head" means in this context. Metaphors that aren't understood by your target audience are most definitely not a sign of eloquence. Eloquence without communication is a fairly meaningless concept, imho.

You may indeed “see that as a sign of eloquence,” but I’d say that this is so only for those metaphors that are well chosen. As to “allowing for easier understanding,” I hope it’s become clear to you that these particular metaphors have only hindered understanding. The only useful standard for clarity is the one judged by the reader, not by the writer.

@PaulTanenbaum Interesting point. Not sure if I agree entirely to let a reader hold my message hostage. But, undeniably, if no reader understands my message, it's a failure on my end. Luckily, at least one useful answer emerged so we're all satisfied, I guess. I'll try to consider less far-fetched expressions in the future. Thanks for the observation. It's useful.

I don't see these terms as being related in a hierarchy.
There is no sense in which "group" is a collection of "areas".
A range normally has a start and end, and includes the things in between.  This means, to form a range, you must have some kind of order (or at least a sense of "between")  "We sell a range of beds, from simple frame beds, to elaborate four-poster-beds"
A group is a more or less arbitrary collection of things.  It is a very general term.  But note, for example, if you sell a group of things, you sell them as a group.  Whereas if you sell a range of things, you sell individual items from that range.
So there is no general hierarchy.  But you should choose the right word according to your particular needs, which may depend on the nature of the "items" and the metaphor you develop.  As you have grouped your "items" into "areas",  you might extend that metaphor and group the areas into "regions".  Or that might not work in your case.  An "agnostic hierarchical ordering" doesn't exist.

Oh, mate, you're so, sooo helpful right now. (Zero sarcasm intended!) You just described (despite me intentionally omitting that info in the question) the precise application of the concepts. The group is, in our case, just a bunch of arbitrary items and those will be handled as a group (according to your statement). Then, the super-group, the collection of groups will be handled not as a whole but each constituting group at a time. The comparison to how to sell items " in group" and "from range" was spot-on. Thanks!

I would suggest tier with a number inasmuch as it is extensible: your hierarchy may grow in either direction, becoming more refined at the tips and more abstract tending towards monadic at the other end. All that rises must converge.
There is no English vocabulary with specific definition with respect to levels in a taxonomy. There are metaphoric borrowings from biology and botany.
